# Making a dictionary of data frames from pandas data frame without writing it to excel file

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe, dictionary, runtimemodification

I have this code that is working but i want to modify it such that i acheive the result with out writing and reading to excel file. Intended out put is given in the end

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['red', 'yellow', 'red'], 'b': [0.5, 0.25, 0.125],'datetime':[2019-1-1, 2019-5-1, 2019-6-1],})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('f.xlsx') ### need to modify this to get dfs a dictionary without wriitng to excel
for unique_var in df['a'].unique():
    frame = df[df['a'] == unique_var]
    frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=unique_var,index=False)
writer.save()

xl_file = pd.ExcelFile('f.xlsx') 
dfs = {sheet_name: xl_file.parse(sheet_name)  ### dfs is the dictionary of data frames
          for sheet_name in xl_file.sheet_names}
```

**Intended Output**

```
dfs['red']
```

[image]

Comment: yes you can, store them in a dict. `dfs = dict(iter(df.groupby("a")))` now try `dfs['red']`

Comment: @anky.can you modify the given code ?by df1 you meant the df???

Comment: edited. yes thats what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The pandas have the method `.to_dict` to do such a things.  you can do  `mydict = pd.to_dict()` and save it to a variable.
see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)